# how to sort a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I know this question has been asked many times but I have yet to see an array built like this.  I have tried some of the numerous examples I have found but none seem to do the trick.

I am editing a PHP program that creates a dropdown list of UPS rates.  The functions in this program create an array that is structured like this.  I'd like to be able to sort this array on [price].

```
Array
(

    [price] => Array

        (

            [0] => 617.75

            [1] => 632.97

            [2] => 782.77

            [3] => 597.93

            [4] => 337.00

        )


    [option_value] => Array

        (

            [0] => 07

            [1] => 08

            [2] => 54

            [3] => 65

            [4] => 11

        )


    [option_name] => Array

        (

            [0] => WorldWide Express

            [1] => WorldWide Expedited

            [2] => WorldWide Express Plus

            [3] => International Saver

            [4] => International Standard

        )


)
```

Comment: Could you please show us these numerous attempts?

Comment: Assuming the other arrays have no relation to the prices array: `natsort($array['price']);`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI wouldn't assume that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It wasn't specified. Assuming is appropriate considering the array design.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑConsidering the array design I assumed the opposite :-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah... Well, I'll go sit over there then :P

Comment: And yes, the arrays do have a relation to each other.  I know the design of this array is strange but that's what I inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ascending, I would try:

```
array_multisort($array['price'], SORT_ASC, $array['option_value'], $array['option_name']);
```

To go along with the other answer to restructure the array:

```
foreach($array['price'] as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array('price'=>$array['price'][$key],
                      'option_value'=>$array['option_value'][$key],
                      'option_name'=>$array['option_name'][$key]);
}
array_multisort(array_column($result, 'price'), SORT_ASC, $result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I tried the array_mutisort function but must have not used it properly.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd refactor the dataset into something sensible:

```
$i = 0;
    $result = [];
    while($i < count($source['price']) ) {
        $result[$i] = [
                'price' => $source['price'][$i],
                'option_value' => $source['option_value'][$i],
                'option_name' => $source['option_name'][$i]
            ];
        ++$i;
    }
```

Then, sort the result using usort:

```
function sort_by_price($a, $b) {
if ($a['price'] == $b['price']) {
    return 0;
}
    return ($a['price'] < $b['price']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($result, "sort_by_price");
```

Answer (score 1):

what will i do is this

```
$price = $array['price'];
asort($price);
foreach($price as $key=>$val){
    echo $val.'='.$array['option_value'][$key].'='.$array['option_name'][$key].'<br />';
}
```

i used asort to sort the value ASC and to preserve the array key. you can also use arsort to sort array value DESC.

asort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

arsort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ar = array(
       array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
       array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
      );
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($ar);
?>
```

**array1_sort_order**

The order used to sort the previous array argument. Either `SORT_ASC` to sort ascendingly or `SORT_DESC` to sort descendingly.

This argument can be swapped with array1_sort_flags or omitted entirely, in which case `SORT_ASC` is assumed.

**Sorting type flags:**

**SORT_REGULAR** - compare items normally (don't change types)
**SORT_NUMERIC** - compare items numerically
**SORT_STRING** - compare items as strings
**SORT_LOCALE_STRING** - compare items as strings, based on the current locale.   It uses the locale, which can be changed using setlocale()
**SORT_NATURAL** - compare items as strings using "natural ordering" like natsort()
**SORT_FLAG_CASE** - can be combined (bitwise OR) with SORT_STRING or SORT_NATURAL to sort strings case-insensitively

SRC: [Example #2 Sorting multi-dimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)